# Is it possible to make the Unity3D UI slider that follows a timeline?

Tags: c#, time, unity-game-engine, slider, unityscript

Basically is it possible to create a slider that works like the slider present in youtube videos with the pause and play button.

The concept for me is to link the slider so that it moves according to a timeline.
The play and pause buttons would then just be used to set Time.timescale

I am relatively new to unity and i don't actually know how to apply the above concept into c# code therefore i cannot provide a sample code.

Can someone give me a rough idea of how it could be done?

[image]

Example of how it would look^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out roughly how to make the slider move according with time

```
public Slider testslider;

void Update () {
        testslider.value += (Time.deltaTime * 0.2f);
    }
```

This will atleast make the slider move by itself.
If u want it to move to a timer you just have to edit abit

Answer (score 0):

Unity UI has [Slider component](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-slider) that you can use for that.